# Tibble columns must have consistent lengths, how to properly extract from lists

Tags: r, purrr, tibble

I'm confused with the following error this function is receiving. It runs smoothly if I drop the `ementa` and `tema`, but by including these endpoints, it breaks because length mismatch. What I'm doing wrong?

```
  download_data <- function(y){

  url = paste0("http://legis.senado.gov.br/dadosabertos/materia/pesquisa/lista?ano=",y)

  request <- httr::GET(url)
  request <- httr::content(request, as = "parsed")

  Materia <- purrr::flatten(request$PesquisaBasicaMateria$Materias$Materia)
  DadosBasicos_df <- purrr::flatten(Materia)
  # AutoresPrincipais <- purrr::flatten(request$PesquisaBasicaMateria$Materias$AutoresPrincipais)

  dados <- tibble::tibble(
  id = purrr::map_chr(Materia, .null = NA, "CodigoMateria") %>% na.omit(),
  nome = purrr::map_chr(Materia, .null = NA, "DescricaoIdentificacaoMateria") %>% na.omit(),
  AutoresPrincipais = purrr::map_chr(Materia$AutoresPrincipais, .null = NA, "NomeAutor") %>% na.omit(),
  ementa = purrr::map_chr(Materia$DadosBasicosMateria, .null = NA, "EmentaMateria") %>% na.omit(),
  tema = purrr::map_chr(Materia$DadosBasicosMateria, .null = NA, "IndexacaoMateria") %>% na.omit())
  dados 
  }
```

Then we run

```
  library(httr)
  library(tidyverse)
  library(jsonlite)
  library(purrr)


  y = 2018
  data <- map_df(y, download_data)




Error: Tibble columns must have consistent lengths, only values of length one are recycled:
* Length 0: Columns `ementa`, `tema`
* Length 2907: Columns `id`, `nome`
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Comment: Why should I? The AutoresPrincipais follows the same reasoning with `Materia$AutoresPrincipais` to get the values properly. Somehow it doesn't work for the other last two endpoints.

Comment: because `Materia$AutoresPrincipais` is a nested list. To access `AutoresPrincipais` you need to do `Materia$AutoresPrincipais$AutorPrincipal$NomeAutor` whereas for `ementa` you need `Materia$DadosBasicosMateria$EmentaMateria`, `AutoresPrincipais` is one level deeper which works with `map_chr` then.